# LinkButton Click event is not firing if we add "data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEmployee" property of linkbutton in aspx file

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a LinkButton that a Bootstrap Modal is assigned to it:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEmployee">
    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/addEmp.png" />&nbsp;Add
</asp:LinkButton>
```

The modal is show up correctly but Codebehind Click Event is not fired:

```
Protected Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType, "Show", "<script type='text/javascript'> $('#modalEmployee').modal('show');</script>", True)
End Sub
```

Comment: did you got any errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnEdit">
   <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/add.png" />&nbsp;Add
</asp:LinkButton>
```

And for the code behind, use:

```
Protected Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    Dim id = SelectedRowID
    If id.HasValue Then

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "Show", "$(document).ready(function() {$('#modalAttorney').modal('show');});", True)

        EditRecord(id.Value)

    End If
End Sub
```

Remember that Javascript events only fire after the document is ready.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Bootstrap, it's a common issue, you can see this link to find out the main reason:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24977515/3878932

But in your case you can use this trick:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAttorney" onclick="__doPostBack('<%= btnEdit.UniqueID %>', '');">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/add.png" />&nbsp;Add
</button>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnEdit" CssClass="hidden"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Set the main button as hidden and use a fake button, fake button fire the modal and then main button is fired automatically.

But i can't understand your code's idea exactly. You show up modal when click on button and then show up it again in codebehind?
Also when you have a full-postback, the modal disappear again unless wrapping button in an updatepanel.

Comment: your OnClick event will will override the Modal, the OP wants to perform an action and show the Modal at the same time.