# Link button doesn't fire click event but triggers modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is how I add data to my repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptNotification" runat="server">
     <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="table table-hover">
           <tr>
             <th>Code</th>
             <th>Description</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Action</th>
            </tr>

     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
           <td><asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("[Group Code]") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("[Description]") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("[Professor]") %>'></asp:Label></td>
             <td><asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnEye" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("[ID]") %>' runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" OnClick="lbtnEye_Click" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                                <!-- <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder> -->
        </td>
       </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
       <FooterTemplate>
       </table>
       </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

So as you can see the linkbutton is added dynamically, I have code inside the `lbtnEye_Click` event but it doesn't hit the click event (I placed breakpoint on it) but it fires the modal.  What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add, OnItemCommand like

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptNotification" runat="server"  OnItemCommand="rptNotification_ItemCommand">
```

Add CommandName in linkButton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnEye" CommandName="EyeClicked" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("[ID]") %>' runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" OnClick="lbtnEye_Click" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></asp:LinkButton>
```

Code behind

```
protected void rptNotification_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "EyeClicked") // check command
    {

      //Your code
   }

}
```

Comment: Additional question, why can't I access the ID's inside the repeater?

Comment: still doesn't hit :'(

Comment: but when i remove the data-toggle and data-target it hits the event WHY WHY WHY

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors and those errors gone when you remove data-toggle and data-target ? Please use Developer Tools to check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119873/linkbutton-click-event-is-not-firing-if-we-add-data-toggle-modal-data-target

Comment: @Sami - Aha. Twitter-Bootstrap. That's the reason... :-)

Comment: Yes, the link I sent you, may have a solution to your problem as well. Happy if helped !

Comment: @Sami - I am not the original poster, but I had a long discussion with him. I could not reproduce his problem. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735237/how-do-i-pass-value-from-a-javascript-function-to-c-sharp-code-behind)

Comment: Correct, sometimes come up with weird issues. vote if this discussion helped.

Answer (score 1):

The C# click event is not triggered because it's being suppressed by javascript.To make sure both the modal is displayed and the server side click event get's raised you need to change the way you display the popup - you should dynamically call the popup from javascript. Like this:

1. Change your link button to be like this:

   ```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnEye" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'
       runat="server"
       CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
       OnClientClick="showPopup()"
       OnClick="lbtnEye_Click">
       <i class="fa fa-eye">
           Click me...
       </i>
   </asp:LinkButton>
   ```
2. Add this to the top of the page:

Javascript and library references:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        showPopup = function () {
            debugger;
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
            return true;
        }
    });
</script>
```